# iPhone : How to create expanadable table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I want to create expandable table view.

I found one [link](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController) which is same as I want.

[image]

But I want to create my own table view (Dont want to implements this github code).

How do I achieve this type of functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

See this nice tutorial:
[Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Demonstrates how you can use animated updates to open and close sections of a table view for viewing, where each section represents a play, and each row contains a quotation from the play. It also uses gesture recognizers to respond to user input: * A UITapGestureRecognizer to allow tapping on the section headers to expand the section; * A UIPinchGestureRecognizer to allow dynamic changes to the height of table view rows; and * A UILongPressGestureRecognizer to allow press-and-hold on table view cells to initiate an email of the quotation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar feature, to build it a rough algorithm will be:

1. implement the uitableviewdelgate and uitableviewdatasource protocols
2. create a global variable expandedSectionIndex = -1;

   = -1 represents all collapsed.

   = 0 represents expandedSectionIndex.

   ```
   //the following protocol definitions will take care of which section is to be expanded.

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
     {
         if(expandedSectionIndex == section) 
              return [self.dataArray[section] count];
         else 
               return 0;
      }

     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     {
        if(self.dataArray)
               return [self.dataArray count]; 
     }
   ```

   define custom header views in – tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:

   - buttons having frame equivalent to header view frame
   - set button tag property with value of section number.
   - associate all buttons with selector - (void)expand:(id) sender;

     ```
     - (void)expand:(id) sender
      {
         expandedSectionIndex = [sender tag];
         [self.tableView reload];
      }
     ```

     for more detail [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/262356/iPhone-Table-View-with-Expand-and-Collapsed)