# how to expand and callspand UITable section by touch particular section iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am parsing xml and got dynamically data and I am stored data in NSMutableArray

and display data in to UItableView, I attached screen shot

[image]

So how can I implement section expand and callspand by tapping section header(2011 COLLECTION)
Please guide me.

**EDIT**

Solved

Comment: Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview

Comment: Check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview and this too http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=338 also check this project for further reference https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView

Comment: @Gill-   tu ethe v ....iphone Developer ???

Comment: check out this answer 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568450/iphone-how-to-create-expanadable-table-view/18843584#18843584

Comment: thank's but i already solve this very long time ago thank's for link